# Same "where = value" clause for multiple joined tables

Tags: sql, where-clause

I need help please.  I have written an SQL with left joins on about 5 tables.

where a.tabledate = 20220301 and b.tabledate = 20220301 and c.tabledate = 20220301
and d.tabledate = 20220301 and e.tabledate = 20220301

Is there not a neater way to do this by typing in date only once (which will be current_date)

Answer (score 0):

I was being a bit slow, the answer is really simple reverse logic.

```
where 20220301 in (a.tabledate,c.tabledate,d.tabledate,e.tabledate,f.tabledate,g.tabledate)
```